# Generalization of Markov's inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

$X$ is a random variable of any sign, such that $\mathbb{E}(|X|^k) $ exists for $k$ positive integer.

My question is: how to show that Markov's Markov inequality can be generalized to the following form

$$ P(|X>\epsilon |) \leq  \frac{\mathbb{E}(|X|^k)}{\epsilon^k} $$

Comment: What have you tried? Also, do you mean $P(|X|>\epsilon)$?

Comment: $\begin{array}{ll}
 \mathbb{E}(|X|^k) &\leq \mathbb{E}\left(|X|^k \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|^k\geq \epsilon^k\}}\right)\\
  &\leq \mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon^k \mathbb{1}_{\{ |X|^k \geq \epsilon^k \}}\right)\\
  &\leq \epsilon^k P\left(|X|^k\geq \epsilon^k\right)
 \end{array}$ 
@jakobdt

Comment: The first two inequalities should be $\geq$ rather than $\leq$. The last one is simply an equality due to linearity of the expectation. Then you are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:-

For positive numbers, is $a>b$ equivalent to $a^{p}>b^{p}$ ? If yes then what can you say about  the event $\{|X|>c\}$ and $\{|X|^{p}>c^{p}\}$ ? . What can you then say about the probabilities of the above events? What can you then do with Markov's inequality ?

Comment: $\begin{array}{ll}
 \mathbb{E}(|X|^k) &\leq \mathbb{E}\left(|X|^k \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|^k\geq \epsilon^k\}}\right)\\
  &\leq \mathbb{E}\left(\epsilon^k \mathbb{1}_{\{ |X|^k \geq \epsilon^k \}}\right)\\
  &\leq \epsilon^k P\left(|X|^k\geq \epsilon^k\right)
 \end{array}$  @Mr.Gandalf Sauron

Comment: You are just reproving Markov's Inequality. What hint did I give? . $|X|>c\iff |X|^{k}>c^{k}$ . So $P(|X|>c)=P(|X|^{k}>c^{k})\leq \frac{E(|X|^{k})}{c^{k}}$ .

Comment: thank you for your help @Mr.Gandalf Sauron

Comment: @learnermathematics You can mark as answer then. It is important to accept answers as otherwise this question would remain in the unanswered tab.